# Rendering a "normal" checkbox with ext.js 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to do something, i think, that should be relatively simple with EXT.js 4, but I can not find an answer.  I'm trying to create a checkbox with a type of "checkbox" currently when I try it renders it as a type="button"

here is a sample of what I'm doing (I belive this code comes from Sencha itself, but it is what I am trying to do)

THIS CODE

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 10,
    width      : 300,
    title      : 'Pizza Order',
    items: [{
        xtype      : 'fieldcontainer',
        fieldLabel : 'Toppings',
        defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
        items: [{
            boxLabel  : 'Anchovies',
            name      : 'topping',
            inputValue: '1',
            id        : 'checkbox1'
        }, {
            boxLabel  : 'Artichoke Hearts',
            name      : 'topping',
            inputValue: '2',
            checked   : true,
            id        : 'checkbox2'
        }, {
            boxLabel  : 'Bacon',
            name      : 'topping',
            inputValue: '3'
            id        : 'checkbox3'
        }]
    }],
    bbar: [{
        text: 'Select Bacon',
        handler: function() {
            var checkbox = Ext.getCmp('checkbox3');
            checkbox.setValue(true);
        }
    },
    '-',
    {
        text: 'Select All',
        handler: function() {
            var checkbox1 = Ext.getCmp('checkbox1'),
                checkbox2 = Ext.getCmp('checkbox2'),
                checkbox3 = Ext.getCmp('checkbox3');

            checkbox1.setValue(true);
            checkbox2.setValue(true);
            checkbox3.setValue(true);
        }
    },{
        text: 'Deselect All',
        handler: function() {
            var checkbox1 = Ext.getCmp('checkbox1'),
                checkbox2 = Ext.getCmp('checkbox2'),
                checkbox3 = Ext.getCmp('checkbox3');

            checkbox1.setValue(false);
            checkbox2.setValue(false);
            checkbox3.setValue(false);
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

RENDERS

```
<input type="button" hidefocus="true" autocomplete="off" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox x-form-cb" id="checkbox1-inputEl" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="">
```

Notice the type="button"? I nee the type to be a "checkbox"

Let me include the reason, maybe I am approaching this wrong.  I am trying to make JAWS reader read the checkbox the way it should.  As a type "button" JAWS reader reads it like a button and dose not read the **label** that goes with the check box.

Hope this makes since, please ask any question you need to and thanks for any help.

Ross

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? 4.1? 4.2?

Comment: Whats wrong with this code I am able to see normal behavior in this.Could you specify some more details.

Comment: The problem here is that <input type="button"> will need an attribute role="checkbox" in order to be shown correctly by JAWS.

Comment: I'm using 4.1.... looks like adding role="checkbox" works.  I'm looking around now, how to add it, but if anyone can't point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using config *autoEl*. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/3262/

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    autoEl: {
        html: '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="topping" >Anchovies'
}
```

If you inspect the DOM, you will be able to see a html input checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so almost 2 years later, here's your answer:

You need to include the css!  It took me hours to figure this out.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/packages/ext-theme-gray/build/resources/ext-theme-gray-all.css">
```

BTW, put a comma after the 3.

```
inputValue: '3',
```

Answer (score -1):

I had run your code at my end and its working fine. I am using extjs 6.0.2 and I think what you are seeing is that box that needs to be checked prefix to the label. It always remains as a button only. Even if you use a radiofield, then also it will be type="button" in dom because that box has to handle click event which can be handled by type="button". Can you provide the reason why you need it as type="checkbox"?

Comment: The reason is in the question.